# Extending google maps Marker class

Tags: java, android

I need to extend this class to add some custom data to each marker as a property.

Can the class be extended? If so how can I add a new property?

Answer (score 2):

> Can the class be extended?

No, as it is marked as `final`. You cannot create subclasses of the Maps V2 `Marker` class.

One workaround is to overload some data member of `Marker`, such as the snippet, to use as the key to a collection of model objects (e.g., `HashMap`) that can contain whatever properties you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here - so if i were to overload the `snippet` where abouts would I create the overloaded method?

Comment: @JoshBoothe: Sorry, I didn't mean `@Overload`, but the more generic term "overload". IOW, put some key into the snippet (e.g., via `snippet()` in `MarkerOptions`) that you can retrieve later (via `getSnippet()`), and use that key to look up the rest of your model data.

Comment: I also tried to extend Marker to add my own position object to it but I ended doing something similar to this. I just needed to add extra info to the title (which requires some calculations) so I put an "id" as title, and then I loaded the title only when the marker is clicked.